# An internal error occurred during: "AppXray Indexing..."

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-luna

I installed Oracle WebLogic Tools for Eclipse Luna and now  I get the error in the title at startup.  I've attached the Eclipse log below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.initialize(MavenClasspathContainerInitializer.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2902)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1937)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:3247)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2857)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1962)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.buildStructure(JavaProject.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getJavaProjectElementInfo(JavaProject.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.newNameLookup(JavaProject.java:2329)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.newNameLookup(JavaProject.java:2339)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.findType(JavaProject.java:1357)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.findType(JavaProject.java:1264)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.jsf.AbstractJSFTechnologyDiscoverer.isActive(AbstractJSFTechnologyDiscoverer.java:68)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.project.technology.DefaultTechnologyDiscoveryProvider.getActiveTechnologyDescriptors(DefaultTechnologyDiscoveryProvider.java:82)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.project.technology.DefaultTechnologyDiscoveryProvider.getActiveTechnologies(DefaultTechnologyDiscoveryProvider.java:64)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.project.internal.ProjectImpl.getTechnologyExtensions(ProjectImpl.java:75)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.project.internal.ProjectImpl.getTechnologyExtensionById(ProjectImpl.java:96)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.javawebapp.app.WebAppClassloaderResetCommand.execute(WebAppClassloaderResetCommand.java:45)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.resources.internal.CommandSetJob.runPreLockCommands(CommandSetJob.java:211)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services.resources.internal.CommandSetJob.run(CommandSetJob.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Answer (score 29):

Try turning off AppXray assuming that you do not need it.

Window -> Preferences -> AppXray

Check the "Disable AppXray" checkbox.

Lastly click "Apply".

Comment: In my version it was Window -> Preferences -> **Oracle** -> AppXray. Still, plus one for giving me a helpful answer :)

Comment: AppXray description http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15315_09/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.webtier.doc/html/files/appXRayOverview.html

Answer (score 13):

In the newer versions of Eclipse to turn off AppXray the path is

window -> Preferences -> Oracle ->AppXray

Comment: Thanks for actually taking the time to copy my own comment into an answer, and actually helping me help myself, two years later ;)